# Need hint for equation system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I stumbled upon the following in an old math book and could use a hint:

> The sum of the volumes of two cubes is 35, whereas the sum of the
>   surface area of the two cubes is 78. Calculate the lengths of the
>   sides of the two cubes.

So, if we let $x$ be the length of the side of one cube, and $y$ be the length of the side of the other, we must have:

$$x^3 + y^3 = 35$$
$$6x^2 + 6y^2 = 78$$

i.e.:

$$x^3 + y^3 = 35$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = 13$$

How to proceed from there? If I try the obvious things like isolating x or y and plug into the other one I get a mess. Is there some type of substitution required?

Comment: If these are supposed to be integers, then trial and error suffice ($x=2,\ y=3$ is one solution).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\,(2,3),(3,2)\,$ are "obvious" solutions, then equating $\,x^6 = (35-y^3)^2=(13-y^2)^3\,$ gives:

$$
0 = 2 y^6 - 39 y^4 - 70 y^3 + 507 y^2 - 972 = (y - 2) (y - 3) (2 y^4 + 10 y^3 - y^2 - 135 y - 162)
$$

What's left to prove is that the quartic factor does *not* have two positive real roots.

Comment: The quartic polynomial has one real root by Descartes rule of signs.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Guess you meant one *positive* root. Right, but the other real root is negative, and for the pair of roots \(\*\) to qualify as a solution, *both* real roots would need to be positive. \(\*\) By symmetry of the original system, both $x$ and $y$ would have to be roots of the same quartic.

Comment: Yes, I meant positive root, thank you.  I was trying to give a hint for why the quartic factor doesn't have two positive real roots.

Answer (score 1):

$35=x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=$

$=(x+y)(13-xy)$

But

$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy=13+2xy$ and so

$xy=\frac{1}{2}[(x+y)^2-13]$ and it can be replaced  to first equation to get that

$35=(x+y)(13-\frac{1}{2}((x+y)^2-13))$

and if you define $z:=x+y$ you must resolve

$70=z(39-z^2)$

(You can observe that the solutions of the equation are  $z=2$,$z=5$ and $z=-7$)

So the form of the solutions of your equations is $(x,z-x)$ where $z$ is the solution of that particular equation. 
Now you can calulate

$x^2+(z-x)^2=13$

and you have that the unique solutions of your sistem are of the form $(x,z-x)$ such that verify the equation:

$ 2x^2-2zx+(z^2-13)=0$

Comment: You have some error, because $z=5$ does not solve your last equation. If you switch it to $35=\frac{z}{2}(39-z^2)$ then you still have a subtlety because the equation has two positive solutions, and you have to determine what they mean for $(x,y)$ (if anything) rather than for $z$. (I upvoted before noticing this error...)

Comment: Thanks you, now it is correct?

Comment: I think you still have the sign error that led to you getting 13/2 instead of 39/2 in the first place.

Comment: You are right !! Thanks you very much

Comment: Now it appears to be correct, though it is mildly annoying to work with because you have to actively rule out the spurious solution $z=2$ to the cubic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from dxiv's answer
$$2 y^4 + 10 y^3 - y^2 - 135 y - 162=( y^2+7 y+18)(2y^2-4 y-9)$$ The first factor does not show real roots. The roots of the second factor are $y_\pm =1\pm\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}}$.

$y_-$ being discarded since $<0$, computing $x_+$ from $y_+$ would lead to $x_+=1-\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}}<0$. Then the only possible solutions are $(x=2,y=3)$ or $(x=3,y=2)$ .